# how to show hidden div on ajax success call in this code section

Tags: java, php, ajax

i want show hidden div on ajax success call but in this code not working please help

> $(document).on('change','.switch input',
>         function () {
>         var ida = $(this).attr('id');
>         console.log($(this).val());
>
> ```
>   if($(this).val() == 'on'){
>     $(this).val('off');
>     $.ajax({
>       url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>promo/dsable_status/'+ida,
>       type:'GET',
>       data:'id='+ida,
>       success:function(data){
>
>
>       },
>     });
>   }
>   else{
>     $(this).val('on');
>     $.ajax({
>       url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>promo/enable_status/'+ida,
>       type:'GET',
>       data:'id='+ida,
>       success:function(){
>
>
>       }
>
>     });   
>   }
> })    </script
> ```

hidden div herer
 Promocode status active

Comment: $( "#theDiv" ).show();

Answer (score 1):

Your success calback is empty do whatever you want in the success callback check this code,

```
$(document).on('change','.switch input', function () { var ida = $(this).attr('id'); console.log($(this).val());

  if($(this).val() == 'on'){
    $(this).val('off');
    $.ajax({
      url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>promo/dsable_status/'+ida,
      type:'GET',
      data:'id='+ida,
      success:function(data){

      },
      complete:function(){
        $('#your_div').hide();   
      }
    });
  }
  else{
    $(this).val('on');
    $.ajax({
      url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>promo/enable_status/'+ida,
      type:'GET',
      data:'id='+ida,
      success:function(){

      },
      complete:function(){
        $('#your_div').show();   
      }

    });   
  }
});
```

Comment: i know but in this code not working div are not showing

Comment: The success calback will only fail if you have a 500 error(php error or any other errors like 404 etc), on that ajax called url, so plz check the php script running while the ajax is called, edited my code, and added complete callback which will run even if the ajax fails

Comment: i checked the script but if and else part both working in same time

Comment: I n which part you need to show the div in **if** or in **else** ??

Comment: I guess when you call promo/dsable_status ,you need to hide the div and when you call promo/enable_status/ you need to show the div Right ??? check the edited answer

Comment: K then accept the answer please and close the topic

Answer (score 0):

Use the "success" callback, Do any thing you want in "complete" callback